# Solve for the Green's function and show is not symmetric even though dirac is.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, greens-function

$$\frac{dG}{dx} + G = \delta(x-x_0)\text{ with }G(x;x_0) = 0 $$

I am somewhat lost in what to do to turn this into a Green's function. My Prof went about it by simply using an integrating factor, but the reasoning behind it had me lost. Isn't the fact that the function is discontinuous mean I can't just simply use an integrating factor over the whole expression? Don't I need to first work it out like this:

when $x$ does not equal $x_0$:

$$   G(x;x_0) = \begin{cases} ae^{-x} & \text{ when }x < x_0, \\
be^{-x} & \text{ when }x > x_0.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: There is no issue in integrating discontinuous functions, only in taking their derivatives. You can use an integrating factor $e^{\int_0^x G(t, x_0) dt}$ without issue.

Comment: so why am I only integrating $$\int_0^x$$ and not $$\int_x^{infiniti}$$ portion?

Comment: You can do either, mine was just an example. For your particular problem, you are right, you will want to integrate from $x$ to $\infty$. What I mean is that you can integrate $G$ with any limits you choose.

Comment: The solution my prof got was:   $$ G(x:x_0) = \int_0^x e^{y-x} \delta(y-x_0) dy $$  Now I get that y is supposed to be a dummy variable of sorts, but when I try and verify that this expression solves the PDE above I get the first delta portion, but the second portion I'm not sure how it goes away. Does it just go away because everywhere that I'm integrating over it will equal 0 except for at $$ x = x_0$$ ?   How did the boundary condition come into play? Just for the integral?

Comment: Are you sure you took the derivative correctly? You need to use [Leibniz's rule with variable limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form_with_variable_limits) to differentiate with respect to x.

Comment: I'm probably not doing it right:   $$\frac{dG}{dx} = \int_0^x \frac{d}{dx}(e^{y-x}\delta(y-x_0)) dy = \int_0^x (-e^{y-x}\delta(y-x_0)dy  $$

Comment: Yes, that is incorrect. Look at the link I gave you to see what the correct rule is when the limits are variable.

Comment: Another quick question, how do I know where I have to "construct" a Green's function by using the sides of where the dirac is defined compared to the approach I just used above?

Comment: There is no general rule, it is just the case that sometimes one will work and the other will not...

Comment: how do you know if one "worked" per se? Oh and I got the solution to that. The derivative turns into the Dirac delta function, and G just equals 0 by our conditions.